# How to count the number of elements of each category in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-queryset

I have a list of elements. There is a 'status' value here. I need a code that in an HTML page will show the total number of items for each 'status'. How to do it?

For intance, there is the list in the page:

```
appnumber status
№54534534 accepted
%46342322 in process
%55745232 accepted
%67456452 denied
%76454534 accepted
%52864525 denied
%86752525 accepted
```

The result should be:

```
accepted - 4
denied - 2
in process - 1
```

My code:

`home.html`

```
<div class="headtext">
    <form method="GET" action="{% url 'search' %}">
        <input type="search" type="text" name="q" prequired placeholder="Put appnumber">
        <button type="submit">Find</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div>
  {% for application in object_list %}
        <div>
            <p>Application: {{ application.appnumber }}, status: {{ application.status }}</p>
        </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

`views.py`

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Application
    template_name = 'home.html'

class Search(ListView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Application.objects.filter(appnumber__icontains=self.request.GET.get("q"))
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["q"] = self.request.GET.get("q")
        return context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Count` with [`annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) so:

```py
from django.db.models import Count

class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Application
    template_name = 'home.html'
    
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        status_counts = Application.objects.values('status').annotate(total=Count('status'))
        context['status_counts'] = status_counts
        return context
```

Then you can use `status_counts` in Template so:

```html
<div class="headtext">
    <form method="GET" action="{% url 'search' %}">
        <input type="search" type="text" name="q" required placeholder="Put appnumber">
        <button type="submit">Find</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div>
  {% for application in object_list %}
        <div>
            <p>Application: {{ application.appnumber }}, status: {{ application.status }}</p>
        </div>
  {% endfor %}

  <h2>Status Counts</h2>
  <ul>
    {% for status_count in status_counts %}
      <li>{{ status_count.status }} - {{ status_count.total }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Sunderam Dubey, Thank you for your answer, but, unfortunately, it doesn't work. The project and the page open correctly, but there isn't any count.

Comment: @Stew but how is it possible, your `HomeView` is a `TemplateView` or `ListView` please confirm it? (As I have seen your previous question)

Comment: I use ListView. As for my previous question, it's just experiment. I use your decision with code which is in this question.

Comment: @Stew So after changing your `HomeView` as suggested in answer, what do you see?

Comment: Please ignore that question. I am using the code from this question.

Comment: Yes, now it works. I really appreciate your effort! Thanks for this easy solution